# Nodejs with flutter project run on physical device

Tags: node.js, api, flutter, ip

I have an API on nodejs and a flutter application. I want to run my flutter application and have access into the API but I don't know the correct ip.

The nodejs runs on localhost:3000 with localhost:3000 also to my project, I don't have access.

Any idea how to solve and get access ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your IPV4 Address instead of localhost.
so from `localhost:3000` => `192.161.1.100:3000`

Can find your address via terminal with command: `ifconfig` (on mac/linux)

Or via cmd: `ipconfig` (on windows)

```
...
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
...
inet 192.161.1.100 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect
status: active
...
```

Comment: It's `ipconfig` on Windows machines.

Comment: So I let the server (API) runs on localhost and set on my program the IPV4 (wireless) and all of this with the same port (3000) ?  ?

Comment: You run your server on localhost. Your physical device is connected to your computer, but can't access localhost, it needs to use your wifi IP address

Comment: You mean use the wifi IPv4 address ? I used it on project code for but also didn't work. Should I use the wifi Ipv4 also to API server? I tried also but nothing..

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the simplest way to do it. For example if your `node` server is running on port `3000` execute this in your terminal:

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Now you can access the `node` server running on `localhost` from your physical device.

Comment: It makes the `localhost` on port `3000` avalible on your phone.

Comment: So I should write both (API server  and Flutter project ) localhost and with reverse the localhost will work for my device ?

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind that you have to put the port that you are running your server on into the command. So if you are using port `5000` it will look like this: `adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000`.

Comment: yes, I'm using 3000 so it's ok. Thanks! I wrote that the reverse is when you are have did a port forwarding.. I have not do any port forwarding so how I will reverse.. Maybe it's by default ?  Also the command adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000 how now that when my phone try to get access to localhost that will give me ? Sorry for many questions but I'm trying to understand this logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how it works in `adb` internally. However, you can search it up on Google, but you don't need to know how it works! :) If this answer helped you please consider clicking on the green checkmark to mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm using MacBook and I got the message zsh: command not found: adb

Comment: Ohhh, I thought you were on Windows working on an Android device. ADB is the Android Debug Bridge and it is only supported on Android devices.

Comment: So for MacBook and iPhone you haven't any solution ? :/